# How to use other class variables in super();?

Tags: java, swing, awt, panel, getter

If I have one class with a variable called name, how would I be able to put it into a super(); constructor in another class? Example:

this class has the variable 'name' and the user picks an individual String for it, so it'll obviously always change based on what the user inputted.

```
String name;

public String getName(){
 return name;
}

 name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Imagine a car, what is it's name?");
    if(name == null || (name != null && ("".equals(name))))   
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input/pressed cancel, closing program.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ah okay, so it's name is " + name);
```

Then in another class I've got this and I want to put the getName into the super(); constructor

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProjectJPanel extends JFrame {

    TestProjectDialog tpd = new TestProjectDialog();


    public JButton b;
    public Color color = (Color.WHITE);
    public JPanel panel;


    public TestProjectJPanel(){
        super(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< want to put the method getName in here
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(color);

    }


        }
```

just a sidenote, I also get errors whenever i try to put tpd.getName or just getName into an output (in a different class) like

```
System.out.println(getName);
```

*Errors when I try to put it into a println*

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
>     - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete    MethodHeaderName
>     - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
>     - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete QualifiedName

Comment: If you're calling a method, you need to put parentheses after the method name, e.g. `System.out.println(getName());`

Comment: You won't have access to the source code of JFrame you can't add anything to it.

Comment: You can extend just like you are doing now.

Comment: I take it `getName()` is in a different class?  Then if you want to use `getName()` when calling `JFrame`'s constructor, you need an object of that class.  You can't get the name of something without knowing what that something is.  So where is this object that you're trying to get the name of?  I don't see one.  Is it `tpd`?  Where is `tpd`'s name set up?  (Actually, `super()` will be called before `tpd` is set up, so that won't help.)

Comment: `JFrame` has a `setTitle` method that you can use later if you can't pass the name in the `super()` constructor.

Comment: @ajb Oh yes, I will do that, thankyou. If you want to put it as an answer I'd be happy to tick if for you.